# arc4random() positive & negative numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, negative-number, arc4random

Can someone tell me how to properly write

```
arc4random() %#;
```

to include not only positive numbers but negative numbers as well?
I'm trying to have an image (SKSpriteNode from Sprite Kit) be able to randomly move in any direction within a 2D environment.

Comment: The example you provided didn't help me understand how to solve the problem. I should have provided a link to it when writing about my problem so others would know I encountered it but couldn't find it valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arc4random()` return type is an `u_int32_t` which is an `unsigned int` so it can't directly return a negative number.
You will need to 'manipulate' it in order to receive a positive or negative range.

First, I would like to suggest to use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of `arc4random() %` since it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

As for your question, you can do the following by subtracting the wanted range.
For Example:

```
arc4random_uniform(100);
```

Will give values between 0 and 99,
But by subtracting 50 like this:

```
arc4random_uniform(100) - 50;
```

We will now get a random value between -50 and 49;

EDIT- If you assign the results to a variable, I think you will need to type cast the `arc4random_uniform` result to avoid compiler warning, although I am not sure if necessary.
So it would look like this:

```
int randomNumber = (int)arc4random_uniform(100) - 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

> to include not only positive numbers but negative numbers as well?

You can't. `arc4random()` returns an unsigned value (`u_int32_t`).

What you *can* do, though, is shift the range of returned values by subtracting half the range. That is, if you'd normally do something like:

```
 int x = arc4random() % 20;
```

to get a value in the range `[0, 20)`, you could instead say:

```
 int x = (arc4random() % 20) - 10;
```

to get a value in the range `[-10, 10)`.

Comment: Hi mate, good answer, I've started to post my answer before you posted yours, so don't think I try to 'steal' an answer. anyway, just a correction of your examples. your first example would return a value between 0 to 19 and the second would return a value between -10 to 9

Comment: @AMI289 I don't disagree that the range is `[0, 20)`, I just chose not to pick that nit in the interest of simplicity. The word *between* is inherently vague as to whether it [includes or excludes](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118403/7225) its bounds, so I'll edit above to state the range explicitly.

Comment: You should use arc4random_uniform to avoid modulo bias when the upper bound isn't a power of two.